# How to replace first two letters of a column value using index

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
d = {'name': ['john', 'tom', 'bob', 'rock', None], 'DoB': ['01/02/2010', '01/02/2012', '11/22/2014', '11/22/2014', '09/25/2016'], 'Address': ['NY', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NY', 'CA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DoB']).month
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DoB']).year
```

[image]

What I want to do: replace first two letters with 'XX' in the name column if year = 2014 .

My code:

```
df.loc[ (df.year == 2014) , df.name.str[0:2] ] = 'XX'
```

First of all I get this error :
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

But even if there was a value instead of None - say 'jimy' - I get following error: KeyError: "['jo' 'to' 'bo' 'ro' 'ji'] not in index"

I also thought of replace method but it only works if you want to replace a given string.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Note that `pd.DataFrame.loc` uses a column label as the second indexer.

```
mask = df['year'] == 2014
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = 'XX' + df.loc[mask, 'name'].str[2:]

print(df)

  Address         DoB  name  month  year
0      NY  01/02/2010  john      1  2010
1      NJ  01/02/2012   tom      1  2012
2      PA  11/22/2014   XXb     11  2014
3      NY  11/22/2014  XXck     11  2014
4      CA  09/25/2016  None      9  2016
```